# Hex edit a dll to change a dependency name?

Tags: c++, c, dll

I have a dll which is dependent of OPENGL.DLL . However, Windows comes with OpenGL32.dll . I want to change this dependency name in the dll binary so it looks for OpenGL32.dll instead. I tried opening it in VS's binary editor but I cant seem to make the name longer. I can for instance change it to OpenDD.dll but I cant add to it. How could I do this?

If I edit it to be like OpenGLAA or OpenGLJU this works but changing to OpenGL32 results in it saying .dll cound not be found

Comment: It seems unlikely that OPENGL.DLL and OpenGL32.dll will be interchangeable.  They are likely different versions.

Comment: no, I have tried it and it works

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself.  It sounds like you are saying that you can edit the binary to change "OPENGL.DLL" (10 bytes) to, for example, "OpenDD.dll" (10 bytes), but you can't change it to "OpenGL32.dll" (12 bytes).  But then you contradict yourself by saying: "If I edit it to be like OpenGLAA or OpenGLJU this works".  So which is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its a bit hard to explain in english how to change the imported dll name in PE
(there're quite a few levels of indirection and RVAs), but
accidentally, I have a library that can be used for stuff like that.
PE32 only, though.

So here's the utility which you can use: http://nishi.dreamhosters.com/dllrepl_v0.rar
(with source).
And here's how it works:
(UpdateImports() does the thing)

```
struct PE_Hdr1 : PE_Hdr {

  void UpdateImports( char* s1, char* s2 ) {
    int c,i,j;
    int p = 0;

    uint ofs = 0x50;
    printf( "Redirecting <%s> to <%s>\n", s1, s2 );
    // store the target dll name to some place in MZ header
    memcpy( &exedata[ofs], s2, strlen(s2)+1 ); 

    uint idtrva = tbl[1].VA;
    PE_IDRec* idt = (PE_IDRec*)&exedata[ RVA2Ofs(idtrva) ];

    for( i=0; i<nIDRec; i++ ) {
      char* dllname = (char*)&exedata[ RVA2Ofs( idt[i].DLLName ) ];
      printf( "dllname=<%s>", dllname );
      if( stricmp( dllname, s1 )==0 ) {
        printf( " -> <%s>", s2 );
        idt[i].DLLName = ofs;
      }
      printf( "\n" );
    }
  }

};

// Usage: dllrepl file.exe file_out.exe msvcrt.dll msvcrt32.dll
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {

  if( argc<5 ) return 1;

  FILE* f = fopen( argv[1], "rb" ); if( f==0 ) return 1;
  FILE* g = fopen( argv[2], "wb" ); if( g==0 ) return 1;

  MZ_Hdr mz; PE_Hdr pe;
  PE_Open( mz, pe, f );

  ((PE_Hdr1&)pe).UpdateImports( argv[3], argv[4] );

  fwrite( pe.exedata, 1,pe.exesize, g );

}
```

The new location for dll name is somewhat hackish, but with allocation of
a safe area in a PE it would get much more complicated.

Comment: The download link is not available now, and the demo source you provide cannot not compile. Please fixed the download link.Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Excellent tool. I just noticed that on the second pass the entry you stored (s2) is overwritten (probably because the "hackish" way you mentioned). Can you see any potential problem with the way you did it? (I didn't try to run UPX or similar tools in the resultant .exe yet, for now I'm trying to understand how to adapt your code to exchange multiple names)

Comment: It uses a fixed location 0x50 in DOS header of the executable (which is basically useless these days). If you want to replace multiple dll names, I guess you can continue writing them after the first one - there's still "unused" space until at least 0xC0 or so. And the proper way to do it would be to add a new section to the exe.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to experiment with creating a "forwarding DLL" named OPENGL.DLL that simply forwards to the OpenGL32.dll:

- Raymond Chen's "Exported functions that are really forwarders" article: [Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060719-24/?p=30473)
- MSDN Magazine, March 2002, "An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format, Part 2": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301808.aspx
- Microsoft System Journal, Sept 1996: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/archive/S202B.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx

Of course, this assumes that the APIs have the same signatures.  If not, then you could write a wrapper OPENGL.DLL that has the right API signatures, then turns around an calls the OpenGL32.dll functions. That might be a tedious task if there's a lot of functions, but if there are differences in the API, something will need to be there to handle those differences.

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a copy of OpenGL32.DLL, naming it OPENGL.DLL instead of editing the binary that refers to it.

It seems likely OPENGL.DLL and OpenGL32.DLL are different versions, and thus you won't be able to swap one for the other.

Comment: Nope, it works and I want to change it to Opengl32 to avoid shipping OPENGL.dll with my app

Answer (score 1):

Don't hex edit your .dll, just link to the correct version of opengl. From http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/gettingstarted.htm#0010:

> If you see files such as opengl.lib
> and glut.lib, these are SGI's
> unsupported libraries for Microsoft
> Windows. They should not be used. To
> use hardware acceleration, the
> Microsoft libraries are recommended.
> [More info on the SGI libraries can be
> found here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120306065059/http://www.opengl.org:80/resources/faq/technical/mswindows.htm#mswi0130). **Always link with
> either all Microsoft libraries (e.g.,
> glu32.lib, glut32.lib, and
> opengl32.lib) or all SGI libraries
> (e.g., glu.lib, glut.lib, and
> opengl.lib). You can't use a
> combination of both Microsoft
> libarires and SGI libraries.** However,
> you can install both sets of libraries
> on the same system. If you use SGI's
> .lib files, you'll need the
> corresponding .dll files installed in
> your system folder. (i.e., linking
> against opengl.lib requires that
> opengl.dll is installed at run time).

Comment: My problem is glu32 crashes while glu does not

Comment: @Jex, what is the crash? Callstack, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the dependency to some name that fits, then create another DLL by that name that forwards all the relevant names to opengl32.dll. From a purely technical viewpoint of directing the calls to OpenGL32.DLL, there should be no problem (other than the fact that it continues to require an external DLL that you may prefer to avoid). If you really need to change the dependency directly to OpenGL32.dll, it's going to be quite non-trivial. For most practical purposes, you need to duplicate most of what the linker does to produce the executable in the first place -- that's theoretically possible, but calling it non-trivial is a serious understatement.

Comment: But it is working, and this solution envolves creating another dll dependency and avoiding dependencies is my point of doing this :p

Comment: @Jex: see edit. The real question is how and why you're producing something that depends on `opengl.dll` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, NEVER rename a system DLL for YOUR purposes.

If you do ANYTHING, COPY it to your .EXE folder and rename it to something like OpenGLMYHACKEDVERSION.dll.  This way it would be IMPOSSIBLE for another app looking for the REAL system .dll to use "your" version of it.